# Listening port's with service name

Tags: bash, iptables, port-forwarding, nftables

I'm looping in listening ports and when looping I want to get the exact service name of the ports for further activity. So how can I get the service name of the ports.

Comment: Which command do you use to show listening ports? Please add the output to your question.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Check `/etc/services`.

Comment: lsof is the command to use. `sudo lsof -V -nP -i4UDP +c0`  will show process and port on 1 line. If you have the ports; `lsof -i :{PORT}`  will work too.